# Power BI - use a lower level search term to filter a table viz at a higher level

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

This might be a basic question, but I'm struggling with it:

I've got a dataset that includes a long list of accounts. Those accounts are all tied to premises. Multiple accounts can exist at the same premise (many to one). No account exists at more than one premise.

I'd like to search by account and return details at its *premise* level. Using the simple dataset below, for example, how can the user enter an account as a search term but return all the names associated with that *premise*?

I realize that one could just search by premise, but the end-user for this case will not (and cannot) have the premise number.

| Account | Premise | Active? | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45623 | 3216 | Y | Jim |
| 92734 | 3216 | N | Sue |
| 37528 | 7645 | Y | John |
| 13465 | 7645 | N | Will |
| 66572 | 1847 | Y | Erin |

Answer (score 0):

Set the relationship to [Bidirectional cross-filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-bidirectional-filtering) for filters to propagate from the "many side of the relationship to the "one" side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I can definitely implement this, but I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve a similar result with a single table/data source. In it's current configuration, both 'premise' and 'account' are fields in a single table. 

If not, I can always add a simple two column table and set the relationship filtering as you described.